# How to add rows with buttons dynamically into table layout to have equal width

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, tablelayout

I would like to add some buttons with equal width into table layout dynamically. I've already tried everything from StackOverflow, but I cann't find a right solution.

This is my initial XML-layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/puzzle_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/levels_label"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayLevels"
        android:background="@color/puzzle_background"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code part:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (i<levelNum) {
    j = i + 4;
    row = new TableRow(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);
    row.setWeightSum(4);
    while ((i<j)&&(i<levelNum)) {
        Button iBtn = new Button(this);
        iBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        iBtn.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
        iBtn.setId(i + 1);
        iBtn.setOnClickListener(btnclick);
        row.addView(iBtn, 4 + i - j);
        i++;
    }
    lTable.addView(row);
}
```

But every time I get 4 buttons in the row which don't really fit into the row. The right button in the row is always out of the screen.

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

With best regards, Alex

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you another way, you could get witdh of your screen by code:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int width1 = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

and next set width of your button by this:

```
iBtn.getLayoutParams().width = width1;
```

or you could else set max width of your button by similar function.
I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

after some try, I have solution:

First, your logic has some problem, `two while loops` equal to `one while loop`. It confused me.

Second, `Button` in android has `default minimunWidth`, so if you `setWidth` of `button` less than `default value`, it will set width with `default value`.

Third, I use `gravity.CENTER` is to have all buttons in `CENTER`.

ok, that is my explain. the following is my code:

```
TableLayout displayLevels = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.displayLevels);
final int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int levelNum = 8;
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
row.setLayoutParams(lp);
row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
int width = (screenWidth - (levelNum)*4)/levelNum;//4: I don't remember name of it. It is default value.4dp or 4px... I don't remember exactly

displayLevels.addView(row);
while (i<levelNum) {
    Button iBtn = new Button(this);
    iBtn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    iBtn.setMinimumWidth(100);//I set 100px for minimunWidth.
    iBtn.setWidth(width);
    iBtn.setText(Integer.toString(i + 1));
    iBtn.setId(i + 1);
    //iBtn.setOnClickListener(btnclick);
    row.addView(iBtn, i);
    i++;
}
```

with:

```
private int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've just tested it and it works! I've compared your code with mine, so the problem was the point with setMinimumWidth, without it it couldn't be shown properly.